# Preventing Quantum Attacks on Cryptography

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

With the advancement of technology in quantum computing, it's becoming more evident that we need to start thinking about protecting the future integrity of our cryptographic standards.  What can we do on binary computers to prevent attacks on cryptographic related items such as password hashes, private keys, and asymmetric key exchange?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I voted to close as a duplicate the other way: I find both the earlier question and its existing answers a better landing point. I flagged for merging.